# trying to build unsigned APK keep getting error Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

hi everyone i am having alot of problems trying to build and export my unsigned APK so i can test on other phones, the error i get is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

If anyone has ran into this issue could you supply me a solution.

Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'something is here'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.madcowstudiosinc.playground"
    minSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'


testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem i ended up putting

```
        multiDexEnabled true
```

into my gradle and then i fixed my implementations some weren't compatible with each other. So i checked and deprecated some implementations, then i got the error of my gradle Lint.lint error, i forget the full error and that the offline mode doesn't work, so i went to my gradle functions and i checked off offline mode on gradle. If you try to do an unsigned APK your phone will not install it and you must Generate a Signed APK.